# WPF Application should start on the Left or Right side on any PC/Laptop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to open my c# application on any PC at the left corner of the screen always (Left or right side of the screen). For this what should I do? I did in this way;

```
<Window x:Class="BPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BPF"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I can set the `Height` and `Width` parameters but the PCs screens are different. I want that on any PC the application should open with full height (Equal to the PC/Laptop screen) with width of 400. 
**I want to make application start on the right side of the laptop/PC screen (On each laptop/PC), Application's right side should be attached with the right side of the laptop screen.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code of your wpf app code behind.

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    var workingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    this.Left = 0;
    this.Top = workingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
}
```

Add xaml code. You have to change this property " **Width="400"** "

```
<Window x:Class="BPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BPF"
   Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

if you want to set right

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    var workingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    this.Left = workingArea.Right - this.Width;
    this.Top = workingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
}
```

I fixed this code and add code for set right.

Comment: But where should I tell the width of application?

Comment: You can set with width to `400` directly in XAML.

Comment: @JaeWoo According to your code, application is not starting from the left side of the screen.

Comment: @Amar Change this part. " this.Left = 0; "

Comment: @JaeWooSo Your code is not working. Kindly see the code again. I want to make application start on the right side of the laptop/PC screen (On each laptop/PC), Application's right side should be attached with the right side of the laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly you could set the `Height` property to `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight` and the `Left` property to `0`:

```
<Window x:Class="BPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BPF"
       Title="MainWindow" Left="0" Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" Width="400">
    <StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: What if I want app in the right corner? I tried it but there is not any property `Right=0`. Secondly, the application is some pixels down. (Not on the touching the top of the screen) when it is started.

Comment: Then you have to write some C# code. XAML is a *markup* language. Set the Left property to SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth - 400 or something alike. And set the Height property to SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight  + some additional offset. You cannot do this in pure XAML.